# MSMQ and only use one Thread in Server

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, servicehost

We have a WCF ServiceHost, wich has a few different Endpoints. One of the Endpoints uses MSMQ. Now we have the Problem, that the Server uses multiple Threads to read from this Endpoint! Is it possible to tell WCF to allow only one Thread using this Endpoint? So that I read one Message after another?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ConcurrencyMode` on the WCF service, take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and) at this link, it should help with your issue.

This link might also be helpful [Should WCF service typically be singleton or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756487/should-wcf-service-typically-be-singleton-or-not)

Comment: I think using ConcurrencyMode might be a problem as it is part of the service behavior and will impact all the endpoints.

Comment: Yes, that changes Behavior for all Clients. And ConcurrencyMode default is "Single" so I don't know what I could do with it, because I didn't change it and I have multiple Threads created from WCF!